# transform Modelica to FMU? How to implement the process through Java

Tags: modelica

everyone. I want to simulate some modelica model, but not use openmodelica or dymola, so I think if I can transform the model code into fmu, then call jfmi to process.
I read the corresponding material, but still can not find some material very clear about the whole process. So, is there anyone know where I can get the detail process or somebody already implemented this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have a Modelica model and you want to generate an FMU, then you'll need a Modelica compiler to do that.  You don't really explain your requirements very well.  For example, Dymola has an interface to Java (although I'm not sure how well supported it is these days).  You could also write Java code to make a "system call" to OpenModelica as well (there may be other more Java friendly ways to use OpenModelica as well).

But assuming that, for some reason, those methods are not sufficient, you might also consider the [JModelica.org](http://www.jmodelica.org) compiler from Modelon or the [CyModelica](http://cydesign.com/cymodelica/) from CyDesign since both of these are implemented in Java.